# Configure Google App Engine production server with SMTP parameters

Tags: google-app-engine, smtp

My Google App Engine application needs to send out emails. On my development server, I have specified my SMTP configuration (host, port, user, password) while starting the server, and App Engine sends emails using the specified SMTP parameters.

How can I do the same with my production server?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to configure it - App Engine automatically sends email sent with the mail API using Google's own SMTP infrastructure.